# Is the "Sponsored links for this tag" ad block visible for everyone?

Tags: discussion, advertising, sponsored-tags, visibility

With regards to the ad block that is shown when you use a sponsored tag in search, or clicking on it from the Tags page, is this visible for everyone or is it hidden for users with rep > X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it should be visible even if you're up there at 10k.

> [image: all your adobe tag belong to adobe]

[10k? What are you talking about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/thanks-to-both-stackoverflow-and-telerik-for-the-awesome-promotion)

Comment: I should also note that I had AdBlockPlus installed on FireFox and they still show up as then as well. I found that surprising.

Comment: In this case, it's in your face! But it looks like the "Sponsored links" section isn't in a DIV marked with "ad" or similar.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's visible for 10k users as well.