# Will there ever be an offer like the Telerik promotional free controls?

Tags: discussion, telerik

I just found out that the **[Telerik offer has been discontinued](http://www.telerik.com/registration-login/stackoverflowregistration.aspx)**. I was chasing this one  hard in the full spirit and what I just saw today was terribly disappointing. Will such an offer ever be available again?

How many of you actually availed the offer while it was alive? Are there any statistics as to how many users actually obtained the controls?

And most importantly again - **Will such an offer ever be available again ?**

**Do you think the Great Telerik Offer should be Re-incarnated ?** Please upvote the comment if you think it should become available again.

Comment: The Great Telerik Offer should be Reincarnated.

Comment: [Let's see](http://www.adamcaskey.com/8_ball_answer.htm)...

Comment: @Evan: you make me laugh.  Thank you for brightening my day!

Comment: I never even knew about this offer.  Too bad, since I tend to buy Telerik products from time to time.

Answer (score 10):

Part of my responsibility as [Community Coordinator](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00005/) of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange is to look for new community enhancement opportunities; cool things we can do for the community and other ways we can give back.

- [T-shirts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/help-design-our-stack-overflow-t-shirts), [stickers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/in-stickers-we-trust/), [sticker giveaways](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/free-trilogy-stickers-for-top-users/), [sticker exchanges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/stickers-for-stackers/), [logo](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/) [design](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/logo-contest-winner-for-serverfaultcom/) [contests](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/logo-design-contest-for-superuser-com/)
- [Dev days](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/stack-overflow-developer-days-conference/), [Computer History Museum](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/our-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/), [giveaways](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/a-little-steam-giveaway/)
- [Donations](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/), [code](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/), [free advertising](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/), and [rewards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/thanks-to-both-stackoverflow-and-telerik-for-the-awesome-promotion)

I'm always interested in hearing new ideas for events, fun contests, cool giveaways, or any new and creative ideas you can come up. **If you have any connections or ideas, [contact me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)**.

The Telerik give-away was something special that Telerik wanted to do, and I thank them for the opportunity they gave users for their contribution to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would very much like to see a Stack Overflow coding contest. Perhaps even an annual one. Prizes could be tangible (cash is always nice! or a new computer...) or intangible (accolades, maybe some "I won teh contests!" flair), or some combination thereof.

Comment: You should post this as a question in itself.

Comment: @fretje - I will once Stack Exchange 2.0 is humming along and I can devote more time specifically to working on these projects.

Answer (score 7):

Who knows? Why don't you ask them, they are quite an approachable and friendly bunch.

I guess they would have been targeting 10K+ users as they would tend to be reasonably experienced developers who would be low maintenance in terms of support, and would likely also own blogs and would generally talk about the componentry, thus promoting it.

I've been using them for a while now, and they are nice  - much nicer than the other major vendor who we switched from. They are certainly worth spending money on.

Comment: I think the biggest benefit for Telerik is putting their product in the hands of people who tend to answer a lot of questions on SO - thus not only low support, but _negative_ support, in that these users will also help others along.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

http://devexpress.com/Products/Free/StackOverflow/

Comment: How new is this?

Comment: I don't know. I just happened to notice it on an ad today but I don't normally read the ads.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's great, and I'd love to see it around.  However, as time goes on, the bar to getting 10k points is lower...people who are less motivated but have been around longer will continue to gain points, and may eventually cross the threshhold (I include myself in that category).  It may be that they are thinking that they want to make the offer to only the "cream of the crop".

Whether or not this is what they are thinking, I have no idea...and even if it is what they're thinking, I'm not making any judgements about whether it is a good or bad idea.  It just seems like a plausible rationale for discontinuing.  (This kind of idle speculation can become moot at some point if they make it known...and I can just delete this "answer".)

Comment: 20k is the new 10k.